# react-native webview some websites don't work

Tags: ios, webview, react-native

I have some issues with WebView component, which doesn't work with some websites, currently I have two examples:

http://cnn.com (error code: 101, the url can't be shown)

realself.com (error code: -1003, a server with the specified hostname could not be found)

Both errors appear after 1-2 seconds, and they are not present in regular UIWebView, without react. I am using react-native 0.22 and iOS 9.2, but I saw these errors with earlier versions of RN too.

Minimal test case (just WebView with one of above urls):
https://rnplay.org/apps/S9ZcTw

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  WebView,
} = React;

var SampleApp = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <WebView source={{uri:'http://cnn.com'}}/>        
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);

module.exports = SampleApp;
```

Maybe someone could help with it?
Regards

Comment: Are you seeing this issue in the Simulator? On device? Or both?

Comment: Same problem here.